# Move a view to a new superview without flickering

Tags: iphone

As part of an animation, I have a view that I want to move deeper into the view hierarchy.  (I previously moved it to the top of the view hierarchy in order to perform an animation that appears on top of other UI elements.)  I'm using this code, which does the correct thing.

```
CGRect rect = self.profileImage.frame;
UIView *sv = self.profileImage.superview;
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.profileImage];
rect = [self.scrollview convertRect:rect fromView:sv];
self.profileImage.frame = rect;
```

However, the view flickers when I do this.  Any ideas how to avoid the flicker?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CGRect rect = self.profileImage.frame;
UIView *sv = self.profileImage.superview;
rect = [self.scrollview convertRect:rect fromView:sv];
self.profileImage.frame = rect;
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.profileImage];
```

or

```
CGRect rect = self.profileImage.frame;
UIView *sv = self.profileImage.superview;
self.profileImage.alpha = 0.0f;
rect = [self.scrollview convertRect:rect fromView:sv];
self.profileImage.frame = rect;
[self.scrollview addSubview:self.profileImage];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f animations:^{
    self.profileImage.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working without a flicker using:

```
CGRect rect = self.profileImage.frame;
UIView *sv = self.profileImage.superview;
CGRect convertedRect = [self.scrollview convertRect:rect fromView:sv];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^(void){
    [self.profileImage setAlpha:0.0];
    [self.profileImage setFrame:convertFrame];
    [self.scrollview addSubview:self.profileImage];
    [self.profileImage setAlpha:1.0];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that addSubview was performed in a background thread. 
You need to perform the change on the main queue, and it should work just fine.

try

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  CGRect rect = self.profileImage.frame;
  UIView *sv = self.profileImage.superview;
  [self.scrollview addSubview:self.profileImage];
  rect = [self.scrollview convertRect:rect fromView:sv];
  self.profileImage.frame = rect;
}
```