# How to bring subView to top from superview of its superview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a view hierarchy as view 1 --> view 2 --> view 3. So, view 3 is subview of view 2 which is a subview of view 1. Now, from view 1, I want to bring view 3 to front without bringing view 2 to front. I cannot add view 3 in window due to relative positioning within view 2.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot .Unless view3 should be removed from view 2 and added to view 1 and then to make it to the front with `bringSubviewToFront:` method.

Comment: This is working. The only missing thing here is that, you need to change the center of view 3 with respect to view 1 co-ordinates.

Comment: of course when you add as the subview to a new view frame change is obvious with respect to the new superview.

Answer (score 0):

See [Move a view to a new superview without flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694541/move-a-view-to-a-new-superview-without-flickering), you can convert the relative frame to window, then add the view to window, this will keep the view 3 on its original frame

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code..

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourview];
```

Comment: This will not work as view3 is not subview of view1 directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access view3 directly without accessing view2.

Try this :

```
[view2 bringSubviewToFront:view3];
[view1 bringSubviewToFront:view2];
```